# Is there a priority in max width css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` with two `div` inside. the container is a `flexbox` and I set the two children's `MAX-width`. as an example

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="one">Hi</div>
    <div class="two">my second div</div>
</div>
```

and scss

```
.wrap {
    display:flex;
    .one{
        max-width:100px;
    }
    .two {
        max-width: 50px;
    }
}
```

Now I always thought that if I resized `.wrap` BOTH will shrink at the same ratio, e.g.: -50px taken from both. but apparently this is not true

Then I thought maybe it has to do with the highest (or lowest) max-width given, again this is not the case

What I noticed is one of them will be shrunk so much before anything hardly happens to the other div, what determine this behavior?
**My question is what determines which one will be shrunk to its max limit first?**
I tried removing the flex and the same result happened so I guess it has something to do with max-width only?

Comment: Unclear. *"My question is what determines which one will be shrunk to its max limit first?"* ... shrink to its max limit? Nothing can shrink to its max limit, because nothing can exceed the max limit.

Comment: @Michael_B setting "max-width" for an element makes it shrink as the container/browser shrinks, I noticed this behavior is weird because one element will shrink so much -pretty much till it has width close to zero- while the other's width will be almost fixed, no change and no shrinking. hope this was clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a `flex` container and the children of it are not specifying `flex-basis` it fallbacks to the item's with, in your case, **computed** item width.

You can use the `flex` property to define the "shrink" / "grow" ratio.

My example will preserve a ratio of 1/3 - 2/3.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.one {
  flex: 2;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.two {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one">Hi</div>
  <div class="two">my second div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, this doesn't answer the question asked, second, saying _"My example will preserve a ratio of 1/3 - 2/3"_ ain't correct. If you narrow it down you will see that.

Comment: try it, when it is narrow, the "wide" part becomes 88px and the "narrow" part is 44px...

Comment: I don't have too, as I know, based on content, it won't preserve 33%/66% ratio, still, make the `wrap` 100px wide and they will be 69px/56px, which proves what I say. So if you gonna help users, make sure what you write is correct.

Comment: Ha, In that case you are right, it will we narrow as the longest word. :]
Thank for clarifying that

Comment: Thank you! while it does indeed work it doesn't work with flex-wrap and I need it :(. but still it doesn't answer the question of what determines which one will be shrunk